# accessing javascript function arguments

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Documentation for JQAjaxSetup>>onError: says:

> onError: anObject
>     "A function to be called if the request fails. The function is passed three
>   arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object, a string describing the type of error that occurred 
>   and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument 
>   (besides null) are 'timeout', 'error', 'notmodified' and 'parsererror'."

I'd like to display the error message using something like

`anAjax onError: ((html jQuery id: someId) before: (MyInstanceOfWAPainter error: 'An error message'));`

How do I do that? Possibly doing it all on the client side.

Comment: I would expect a block after onError:. Since I don't know seaside I might be wrong especially while talking of Javascript. `anAjax onError: [ ((html jQuery id: someId) before: (MyInstanceOfWAPainter error: 'An error message'))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the error happens client-side and you probably have a failing connection in such an event, you need to generate the complete javascript code that will display the error (i.e. without rendering callbacks to Seaside).

The snippet below will generate a JS function with two arguments. The body of the function is the jQuery expression that will put the error message (inside the `_error` variable) right before the html dom element with id `someId`.

```
anAjax 
   onError: (((html jQuery id: someId) before: (JSStream on: '_error'))
                           asFunction: #('_XMLHttpRequest' '_error'));
```

Personally, I would not use Seaside's JS-generation functionality here if the id in `someId` is not dynamically generated. If it's dynamically generated from within Seaside, the first snippet might still be easier.

```
anAjax onError: (JSStream on: 'function(_XMLHttpRequest,_error){
                                  $(''#someId'').before(_error)})
```

Comment: Based on what you wrote I made something up, but I don't speak JS so I'm not very comfortable with it. I'd still like a smalltalk solution. `onError: ((JSStream on: '$("#',someId,'").before(_XMLHttpRequest.responseText)') asFunction: #('_XMLHttpRequest' '_error'));`

Comment: Well, you _could_ make the error-handling function make an ajax call back to Seaside, but since you just got an error back it's either not reachable or in a bad state. The best solution is to write your own exception handler in Seaside and make it render what you want in Seaside _before_ sending the response back to the ajax handler. The function you wrote above should then only insert the generated html in the right place. You will not be able to do without any (seaside-generated) JS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can do below to show the error:

```
onError:function(_XMLHttpRequest, _error) {
 alert(_error);
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but I need it in smalltalk. I'm pretty sure Seaside can insert raw javascript, I just haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 0):

this basic idea would be:

jQuery ajax onError: (self javascript alert: 'error')

see JQAjaxTest>>testOnError.